# Executing SQL via PHP after a certain time

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Thanks for at least looking at this question.

I run a small website which allows people to sign up for a premium account. I control this via a group in an SQL database. So if group_id is 5 is premium. Currently I update this all manually but I'd like to have a php script that connects to SQL where a date is stored for when the account expires which'll just change the group_id back to 4.

If anyone can help I'd really appreciate it, or if you need any more information please ask :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the kind of thing a [cron job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) is perfect for. Write a php script that does the changing of the `group_id` based on the date, and set up a cron job to run the script at regular intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Using cronjobs, check this tutorial:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2/

Just check if the account is expired, run the cron 2 times a day ...

Answer (score 0):

Update table set group_id = 4 where date('xxxxxxxx') < [what ever date you enter];

Answer (score 0):

CRON? Or if that isn't available then you can create some logic based on the logins to your page (check the expired account on every login).

Answer (score 0):

You can [run a PHP script as a cron job](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/php-cron-job/) if you're using linux or as a scheduled task if you're using Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just check the expiration time in your query instead of group, **like everyone else do?**